# why ng-Value is not working with simple variables?

Tags: angularjs

This code works great. When we select the radio button it display the value.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var sampleApp = angular.module("sampleApp",[]);
sampleApp.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.names = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
    $scope.beststudent = {studName: "d"};
}])
</script>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="radio" name="sudents" ng-model="beststudent.studName" ng-value="name">     {{name}}
 </li>
</ul>
Selected Value is: {{beststudent.studName}}
```

But this is not working when i declare beststudent like this,

```
$scope.beststudent = "d";
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="sudents" ng-model="beststudent" ng-value="name">{{name}}
```

Why do I need the values in key-value pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of how **[scopes work](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)** and because `ngRepeat` will create a new child-scope for each `<li>`.

If you use an object for `$scope.beststudent` (e.g. `{studName: 'd'}`), then the child-scope will update the parent-scope's `beststudent` property.
If you use a primitive (e.g. string) for `$scope.beststudent` (e.g. `'d'`), then each child-scope will create a local variable named `beststudent` (and not update the parent-scope's property).

This is basically because of how JavaScript's prototypal inheritance works (it's not Angular specific).

Comment: But why does javascript overrides the scope of simple values not the objects?

Comment: @user3427540: The link I provided has a nice illustration of what is going on. If you are asking why JavaScript is implemented this way...well I can't tell much more than that's how it is :)

Comment: I have gone through the blog its too nice, I understood the concept but still now sure why javascript works in that way. Thanks a lot for the link.